# How to represent ASCII code 16 as a character?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, buffer-overflow, payload

[C language] [Linux]

"ASCII code 16 is represented by the control character ␐ also known as the data link escape"

I want to take this character from the keyboard as an input to a program that allows you to do a buffer overflow. It works only if i overwrite an INT variable with this value: 1161258512.

I don't know how to build this number because it s not possible to write the single character 16 as an input. I also tried with the escape sequence but it didn't work. Maybe i should use unicode to do that and write the first 2 characters (with the 16 included) of the 4 byte payload.

I'm new to this kind of things so please if you know more i would really appreciate it

Comment: You can't in standard C. First terminal has to know how to handle it. But of course you can trite your own terminal program which will handle it. First show the code you have.

Comment: You want to take it from the keyboard-  I assume you're using scanf?  A lot of that will really depend on the terminal app you run in-  a terminal may send a ctrl-key combo as a control code, but it isn't something a program can enforce.

Comment: On Windows, to enter an ASCII character 16, hold down the alt key, press 1 6 (I think you may need to use the numeric keypad), then release the alt key.

Comment: Or type the key combination `Ctrl` + `P`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it s not possible to write the single character 16 as an input

This is a strange expression. DLE is 0x10, 16, as you know.

How to get this from the keyboard depends much of many things you did not disclose: what OS?

#### The control key on input

The effect of pressing control as you type a key is to *mask* bits 5 and 6, those with values 32 and 64, so this is your answer:

you can use Ctrl+P, Ctrl+p or Ctrl+0 since there 3 possible values:

- `0` is 0x30
- `P` is 0x50
- `P` is 0x70

But to read this you need to prepare your keyboard driver.  Under Linux and family pos-Unix use *raw input* and under Windows call [ReadConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) or similar.

In short you save the input configuration, prepare it to some that suits your needs, such disabling echo and buffering, then read the key codes. And at the end you restore everything.

Microsoft have a [Console Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-reference). Under Linux `man` is your friend. Look for `raw io` and `ioctl`

Answer (score 0):

The DLE control character can be written in C as `'\x10'`.

Entered it can often be as **Ctrl-O**.
Maybe also **Alt 016** will do in Windows

There is also a represention of the control characters in Unicode, what you did show, showing in one symbol "DLE". Just for manuals describing control characters. DLE = U+2410 = `'\u2410'`. Your 1161258512.

As DLE is an escape, you might expect other bytes to follow.